# How to iterate an animation infinitely in Angular

Tags: javascript, css, angular, typescript, angular-animations

I want to iterate animation infinitely and stop and start in my component. I have written the below code:

```
@Component({
  selector: 'page-login',
  templateUrl: 'login.html',
  animations: [
    // Each unique animation requires its own trigger. The first argument of the trigger function is the name
    trigger('run', [transition('void => *',[animate(1000, keyframes([
      style({transform: 'translateX(0)    rotateY(0)',        offset: 0}),
      style({transform: 'translateX(10%)  rotateY(70deg)',    offset: 0.33}),
      style({transform: 'translateX(20%) rotateY(30deg)',   offset: 0.66}),
      style({transform: 'translateX(0%)',                  offset: 1.0})
    ]))
    ])  
  ])  
]
})
```

In the HTML file I have written below code:

```
<img  @run id="animicon" src="assets/.../logo_1.png" style="background:black" class="image--background">
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Using Angular animations would be incorrect in this context. They are intended to be used when the component is added via router or *ngIf or programmatically, when the regular/plain CSS cannot be used or wont work.
Adding them would only make your code unnecessarily complexe, even slow.
For the case you described in your post, you don't need an Angular animation, plain css animation is plenty enough:

**CSS**

```
@keyframes myAnimation {
  0%   {transform: translateX(0) rotateY(0)}
  33%  {transform: translateX(10%) rotateY(70deg)}
  66%  {transform: translateX(20%) rotateY(30deg)}
  100% {transform: translateX(0%)}
}

img {
  animation: myAnimation 5s infinite;
}
```

[Demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-sg1gkp)

---

However, if you still want to use Angular approach, here is a take.

ts:

```
.....
animations: [
    // Each unique animation requires its own trigger. The first argument of the trigger function is the name
    trigger('run', [
      transition('* => *', [
        animate(
          1000,
          keyframes([
            style({ transform: 'translateX(0)    rotateY(0)', offset: 0 }),
            style({
              transform: 'translateX(10%)  rotateY(70deg)',
              offset: 0.33,
            }),
            style({
              transform: 'translateX(20%) rotateY(30deg)',
              offset: 0.66,
            }),
            style({ transform: 'translateX(0%)', offset: 1.0 }),
          ])
        ),
      ]),
    ]),
  ],

  ....
  trigger: boolean;

  ngOnInit() {
    setInterval(() => (this.trigger = !this.trigger),1000);
  }
```

HTML:

```
<img
  [@run]="trigger"
  .....
/>
```

[demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-wywpsu?file=src/app/app.component.ts)

Comment: Maybe the solution is working, but this is not answering the original question. Don't take it personally, didn't mean to insult you. Actually, I am looking to not use CSS animations because of a memory leak bug in the chromium web view.

Comment: Yes, I moved to angular animations. And the memory leak is gone...Thanks.

Comment: Wow, thanks. This is one that is better than what I have implemented.